# Strange behavior when an activity is launched the second time

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have an `Activity1` which launches `Activity2`. `Activity2` has a list which shows some values from database.

When the `Activity2` is launched for the first time the list shows the correct information, but if I press back button and then launch the `Activity2` again it loads the information correctly from database but it's not displayed on the list.

The code to start `Activity2` from `Activity1`:

```
final Intent int2 = new Intent(getActivity(), CombinationsManagerActivity.class);
MyActivity.insertSomeExtraInfoToTheIntent(int2, currentEmployee.id);
getActivity().startActivity(int2);
```

And the `Activity2` list code is this (I call it when the activity is register with a server (after onResume)):

```
private void fillList() {

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_combinations);
        ZKEmployeeLoginCombination combinations = ZKEmployeeLoginCombination.selectLoginCombinationsByEntityID(this, idEmployee);
        LoginCombinationsListAdapter adapter = new LoginCombinationsListAdapter(this, combinations, enrolledTypes);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Also, `Activity2` manifest declaration:

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.blabla.android.app.employeemanagementv3.CombinationsManagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/combinations_manager" >
        </activity>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don´t know realy why this happens, but what about if You are call finish(), when You press back button in second activity? Have You tried this?

Comment: where did u call this method fillList() .

Comment: Another possibility is that Activity2 is opened in the same task every single time. A suggestion is to add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in your manifest

Comment: Hi @Opiatefuchs, thank you for your answer, I've tried it, but the result is the same: after call finish and start the activity again it doesn't display the list

Comment: @Sam I call fillList() after onResume() when I receive the connection from a server

Comment: just call that method in onResume();

Comment: Thanks @verybadalloc, I tried it, but the result is the same.

Comment: @Sam Thanks for your time :), I need to do it after onResume, because I need the data from server. Anyway Activity2 lifecicle is onCreate -> onResume -> afterServerConnected()-> fillList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the bug on my code: For project requirements we keep some structures to act as listeners from server events. And `registration` was one of them.

The way to register the listeners from the activity was:

```
private static IncomingEventHandler eventHandler = new IncomingEventHandler();
...
if(eventHandler.get(this.name) == null){
eventHandler.add(this.name, this);
}
```

So I was keeping the reference from the previous activity, and then, when the activity receives a `registration` event we were doing in post:

```
referenceToActivity.doSomeStuffOnUIThreadAfterRegister();
```

This works well the first time, but in the second execution referenceToActivity were pointing to the first activity

Answer (score 0):

You probably only ever want there to have one Activity2 alive in the app.  If so, I suggest that you include the following in the manifest for Activity2

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

That may solve your problem. For an explanation, see [the android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it (also singleTop), but the result is the same.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure.  I suggest you debug by adding loads of `Log.d(...)` to determine the execution path, also to work out whether the second activity2 object is the same object as the first time, look for the activities getting created and destroyed to check that's all working properly, etc etc.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try by putting this code snippet on your Activity2 class

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent startNewActivityOpen = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);
        startActivity(startNewActivityOpen);

    }
```