# Strange thing when restarting activity

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a problem with my activities.
I think the problem is nearly the same like in
[this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085530/strange-behavior-when-an-activity-is-launched-the-second-time)

The problem is. That I haven't got a listView. I have a datePicker

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat year_sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat month_sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M");
        SimpleDateFormat day_sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d");

        year = Integer.parseInt(year_sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
        month = Integer.parseInt(month_sdf.format(cal.getTime()))-1;
        day = Integer.parseInt(day_sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     year, month,day);}
```

And here I have the function which is called when the finish button is pressed on the datePicker:

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener 
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        Log.e("TCPClient","datePicker is there");
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth+1;
        day = selectedDay;

        StringBuilder dateOfDelivery = new StringBuilder().append(day).append(".").append(month).append(".").append(year);}
```

I think like in the other post, the datePicker wants to point on an object which does not exist.

Thank you very much. For your help.

Comment: Please add more details on the actual problem.

Comment: A couple of things to understand.  The DataPicker doesn't "want" to do anything.  It works with whatever objects your code uses.  Secondly, you must post the logcat stack trace for people to be able to help.

Comment: I would try to ask your question in a way that doesn't require us to open a second question. Because now it's really confusing.

Comment: the problem is, that there isn't any logcat stack trace. there is no error message when clicking on the finish button. Only the app freezes.